# Getting permission denied issue after adding Maven bin to PATH variable, unable to add to PATH in root mode as well

Tags: macos, maven, installation

I followed the steps mentioned in https://dzone.com/articles/installing-maven.

I am able to echo my mvn bin -

```
SandeepanNath:~ sandeepan.nath$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/apache-maven/bin
```

However, I am unable to run mvn commands still. I get permission denied -

```
SandeepanNath:~ sandeepan.nath$ mvn -v
-bash: /opt/apache-maven/bin/mvn: Permission denied
```

If I try running after sudo, I again get command not found -

```
SandeepanNath:~ root# mvn -v
-sh: mvn: command not found
```

I checked I don't have mvn path defined in $PATH variable in root mode. Do I need to add it here as well? I cannot find the .bash_profile for root though.

Comment: Do you have execute rights on the `/opt/apache-maven/bin/mvn`?

Comment: @Lesiak thanks! That was the issue :)

Comment: Posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user needs to have execute rights on the `/opt/apache-maven/bin/mvn`